# How to check if the value exists in a select2 dropdown with tags: true using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Please find below my select2 dropdown:

```
<select class="skill-select form-control" name="name" required="true" id="skill-name">
                  <option id="xxx"></option> <!-- Needed for select2 -->

                    <option value="33">good</option>

                    <option value="32">sdw</option>

                    <option value="18">PM</option>

                    <option value="17">TL</option>

                    <option value="ddddd" data-select2-tag="true">ddddd</option>
                    <option value="11" data-select2-tag="true">11</option>

              </select>
```

Javascript:

```
  $(".skill-select").select2({
    placeholder: 'Skill Name',
    tags: true
  });
```

How do I access the options present in my dropdown excluding the options with data-select2-tag="true".

In the above example I do not want to access the options 'ddddd' and'11' which have data-select2-tag="true"??

Currently I am using the below java script but this does not exclude the options 'ddddd' and'11' which have data-select2-tag="true";

```
    var opt = $('#skill-name :selected').text();
    var valid;
    var length = $('#skill-name option').filter(function() {
          return $(this).text() === opt;
      }).length;
      if(length != 0){

        valid = false;
        return;
      } else {
        valid = true;
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried the Attribute Not Equal Selector?  https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script worked for me:

```
addSkill = function() {
    var opt = $('#skill-name :selected').text();
  var length = $('#skill-name option').not( "[data-select2-tag='true']").filter(function() {
                  return $(this).text() === opt;
                }).length;
  if(length != 0){

    valid = false;
    return;
  } else {
    valid = true;
  }
```